# Can CMY be additive and RGB be subtractive?

Tags: optics, visible-light

Related: [Why is there a difference between additive and subtractive trichromatic color theories?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/23830/120802)

RGB is additive color and CMY(K) is subtractive.

If you built an electronic screen with CMY subpixels, you'd be able to mix colors additively. Cyan + Magenta = Blue, Cyan + Yellow = green, and Magenta + Yellow = Red. Can CMY be additive and RGB be subtractive?

[image: A photo composed of only Cyan, Magenta, and Yellow pixels.]

The photo is composed of only Cyan, Magenta, and Yellow pixels (before Stack Exchange's image compression). It appears pixelated/jittered, but a real CMY display would properly reproduce the colors.

Comment: At first, it seems highly unintuitively what you describe in your first claim, that one can mix CMY pixels, just in the same way one can do with RGB. Is that a personal experience you have made, your is it something you just assume? Or am I stupid and don't know something that everybody else knows?

Comment: I'm not an expert in the human visual system, but I think you should definitely document the claim *"If you built a computer screen with CMY subpixels, you'd be able to mix colors additively."* if you can, because my first reaction is that this is not the case.

Comment: Nice image, and it does lend weight to your theory, but of course we're still viewing it with RGB pixels. But how do you propose to make yellow in subtractive RGB? Red pigment + green gives a brownish colour.

Comment: Without a comparison to the original we don't learn much, though I notice there are no highly saturated reds or blues in the image you've chosen (or if there were they are not properly represented).

Comment: The Wikipedia article on colour [gamut](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamut) has some relevant information.

Comment: Also, be sure to realize the difference between a CMY color editor program with color picker vs. the fact that pixels on computer screens are always RBG.  Data may be stored in computer memory as CMY, but it gets converted to RBG before being sent to any screen.

Comment: I guess to address your question directly, CMY are the primary colors of subtractive color mixing while RBG are the primary colors of additive color mixing.  It can never truly work the other way around.

Comment: @the_photon It can't be that simple.  If you view a trio of bright CMY-filtered *lights* at a distance, certainly they won't subtract to appear black.  Also, the question is then exactly what cyan, magenta and yellow or red, green and blue you choose as your primaries.  These can and do vary and the color system still "works."  So, why wouldn't you be able to vary RGB "all the way" to its complement of CMY, or vice-versa?

Comment: The reason RGB emissive (additive) displays can't create all colors humans perceive is because for some colors, one of the values of R, G, or B would need to be negative. But an additive display can only emit positive values. On the flip side, subtractive displays can only reduce how much any particular wavelength striking it is being reflected. So colors that would need one of the CMY values to be *positive* are not reproduceable using subtractive colors. If CMY were used for emissive displays, even more colors would need negative values than is the case using RGB.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No additive CMYK doesn't cover enough of the [chromaticity diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamut) to replace RGB. In fact RGB doesn't do a great job of showing all the visible colours.

[image: cie diagram]

The available CMYK colours are those inside the 5 sided magenta box. You can of course make a picture using additive CMYK which only contained shades inside that box.

(sorry SO won't upload the full size svg image)

Comment: FWIW, you can put your SVG onto GitHub as a Gist, and the preview will display it. Eg, [this](https://gist.github.com/PM2Ring/fbe0ea1cb434602ca3a90060e4c55493) At least, it does on the desktop view, but sadly not on the mobile.